# How can conditional be substituted with a function of same variable?

Tags: conditional-probability, conditioning

I was studying on a PAMI article and I have seen an equation like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
P(B|X) &= \prod_c{P(B^c|X)} \\
   &= \prod_c{P(B^c|A^c)}
\end{align*}
$$

where $A^c$ is a function of $X$.

I know to fully understand the derivation details are needed, but what I am wondering is in under what circumstances we can substitute the conditional with a function of the variable?

It does not seem nice to me, because the result of the function may not carry all the information.

The details, motivation, explanation are not given regarding to this substitution in the paper, so I am stuck. The rest of the paper is well written except a few unimportant typos, so I am assuming this is something that I don't know.

Edit: $c$ is not for complement. $B$ is a vector where every element of is independent of each other. $A$ is a vector with same dimensions as $B$. $c$ is an index for the vector's element.

My main area of work is not statistics, sorry for any unclear points.

Comment: In probability theory, superscripts $\!^c$ often denote complements: $A^c$ is the complement of $A$ in the sense that $A^c$ occurs exactly when $A$ _does not_ occur. Here you are using $c$ as a indexing variable in your product as well as what seems to be complements, or maybe not.  Please clarify.

Comment: Please also clarify $B$ and $B^c$.

Comment: I think I have clarified the variables, is it better?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that they are representing $B$ as the intersection of independent (conditioned on $X$) events. In other words: 
$$P(B|X) = P(\bigcap_c B^c|X) = \prod_c P(B^c|X)$$
and then for the second equality, one possible explanation would be that $A$ can also be written as the intersection of events such that we have
$$P(B^k|X) = P(B^k|\bigcap_c A^c) = P(B^k|A^k)$$
This equality would need philosophical justification. It has a bit of a Markovian flavour to it $(P(Z_n | \cap_{k<n} Z_k) = P(Z_n|Z_{n-1}))$, but without knowing more about the paper, I couldn't speculate further.